# How to create a custom sort for a list of strings

Tags: python, sorting, plotly-python

I'm working to create some visualizations and I've got some decent ones going with Plotly, and technically my plots are working.  However, I've got a variable that I'm using as an axis for a couple plots, based on economic group.  Plotly (or python) is defaulting to an alphabetical sort.  This leads to my groups sorting High Income -> Low Income -> Lower Middle Income -> Upper Middle Income

This isn't a logical progression, and I'd like a way to be able to have it sorting so that it goes Low -> Lower Middle -> Upper Middle -> High.  I'm currently using pandas and plotly.express in the project I'm working on, so I'd prefer solutions that work with those or base python, but open to others if I need them.

code for the plot:

```
fig4 = px.histogram(flat_f4, x = 'World bank income group', y = 'Percentage', color = 'Age group', barmode = 'group')
```

Comment: Show the code you're using to make the plot.  I'm guessing plotly has a simple option to let you specify the axis exactly.

Comment: @MarkRansom I've added the code.  As far as I can tell from the plotly documentation, there's not a way to specific the order of the list on an axis

Comment: You need to use the `category_orders` argument : https://plotly.com/python/categorical-axes/

Comment: There's an example right in the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/), look for the section titled "Histograms on Categorical Data".

Answer (score 1):

https://plotly.com/python/categorical-axes/

```
fig4 = px.histogram(
    flat_f4, 
    x = 'World bank income group',
    y = 'Percentage',
    color = 'Age group',
    barmode = 'group',

    # add this bit...
    ##################

    category_orders = {
        "World bank income group": [
            "Low", 
            "Lower Middle", 
            "Upper Middle", 
            "High"
        ]
    }

    ##################

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is similar solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# This Assuming you have created your flat_f4 DataFrame before this point

# Then for example,  you might load it from a CSV file 

# flat_f4 = pd.read_csv('your_data.csv') 

# Create flat_f4 DataFrame

#  Make sure you set the category order directly in the px.histogram function

fig4 = px.histogram(
    flat_f4, 
    x='World bank income group',
    y='Percentage',
    color='Age group',
    barmode='group',
    category_orders={
        "World bank income group": ['Low', 'Lower Middle', 'Upper Middle', 'High']
    }
)

# Show the plot
fig4.show()
```

Comment: It's the ***same*** as my solution, only with different formatting.

Answer (score -3):

To create a custom sort for a list of strings in Python, you can use the sorted() function with a custom sorting key function. Here's an example of how to do this:

```
# Define a custom sorting key function
def custom_sort_key(s):
    # Define your custom sorting criteria here
    # For example, you could sort based on string length
    return len(s)

# List of strings to be sorted
my_list = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "date"]

# Sort the list using the custom sort key function
sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=custom_sort_key)

# Print the sorted list
print(sorted_list)
```

In this example, the custom_sort_key function defines the custom sorting criteria. You can customize this function to define any sorting logic you need, such as sorting based on a particular pattern, length, or any other property of the strings.

When the sorted() function is called with the key parameter set to the custom sort key function, it sorts the list based on the custom criteria defined in the custom_sort_key function.

Adjust the custom_sort_key function to match your specific sorting requirements for your list of strings.

Comment: The question about the sorting within plotly express, ***not*** sorting a native python list.

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?